# Match two dataframes to select items having exactly matching line items

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select the data from "table" that are exactly matched with the data in "criteria" dataframe.

```html
import pandas as pd
table = pd.DataFrame(data = {'RowID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                             'CusID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                             'Area':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B'],
                             'Income':[800,900,1000,900,1000,800,400,400,900,1000],})
 
 
criteria = pd.DataFrame(data = {'CusID':[1,2,4],
                             'Area':['A','A','B'],
                             'Income':[800,1000,700],})
```

As per the criteria i'm expecting the rows of RowID 1 & 5 only. I tried with below code.

```html
tableMatched= table[(table['CusID'].isin(criteria['CusID'])) & (table['Area'].isin(criteria['Area']))& (table['Income'].isin(criteria['Income']))]
```

However according to my code i'm getting RowID 3,6 & 10 also.
That is my expected result is;
RowID       CusID      Area    Income
1            1             A        800
5            2             A        1000

Apreciate if someone can help me to code this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) only, if no parameter `on` it join on all same columns in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = pd.merge(table, criteria)
print (df)
  Area  CusID  Income  RowID
0    A      1     800      1
1    A      2    1000      5
```